# c++ template member function instantiation when using lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, template-meta-programming

the small piece of code below compiles and runs

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    template<class T2>
    void f(T2 a);
};
template<class T>
template<typename T2>
void A<T>::f(T2 a){a();}
int main()
{
    A<int> ac;
    ac.f([](){cout<<"bla"<<endl;});
}
```

but when split into files
hpp:

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    template<class T2>
    void f(T2 a);
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
template<typename T2>
void A<T>::f(T2 a){a();}
```

and main:

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    A<int> ac;
    ac.f([](){cout<<"bla"<<endl;});
}
```

I get a compile time error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
a.hpp:5:10: error: ‘void A<T>::f(T2) [with T2 = main()::<lambda()>; T = int]’, declared using local type ‘main()::<lambda()>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
    5 |     void f(T2 a);
      |          ^
a.hpp:5:10: warning: ‘void A<T>::f(T2) [with T2 = main()::<lambda()>; T = int]’ used but never defined
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find main.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I presume that I need to instantiate the template in the cpp file, eg.

```
template void A<int>::f<>();
```

but I have failed so far to get the syntax right. Since the function argument of "f" in main as a lambda I am wondering whether that is possible at all.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: There is two templates, the class and the function. Im presuming you would need to explicitly instatiate both for this to work, but since the function is called with a lambda from another TU you can't explicitly instatiate it. Generally you keep the implementation in the header for templates.

Comment: Hi. Thank. However, keeping all in the header circumvents the problem but doesn't solve it.

Comment: Keeping all in the header is the idiomatic approach. But if you absolutely don't want that, you have to move away from using lambdas, as their type are unique for each lambds and generated by the compiler. AFAIK there is no way to explicitly specify the type of a lambda.

Answer (score -1):

Each lambda has its own distinct type, and it cannot appear in unevaluated contexts (at least until C++20), that includes function tempalte arguments. You can do:

```
void A<int>::f<std::function<void()>>();
```

At the price of instantiating a function object, or move the code together, as in your first exmaple.